# I am using data Tables in asp.net core it's working fine but some of thing not coming properly. for example my pagination is just a link

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, datatables

[In This Image My image Pagination design is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5hI7.png)

[I want design like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsCI3.png)

My Java script code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AllUsers').DataTable({
            processing: true, // for show progress bar  
            serverSide: false, // for process server side  
            filter: true, // this is for disable filter (search box)  
            orderMulti: false, // for disable multiple column at once  
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            pageLength: 5,
            lengthMenu: [1, 3, 5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500],
            deferRender: true,
            paging: true,
            scrollY: 200,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller: true,
            "columnDefs":
                [{
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                }],
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please include your scripts/styles and how you have them ordered? I have seen this issue before. Also, you can manipulate the HTML DOM with the `dom` option

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Hello, world!</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link type="text/javascript" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: thank you brother, I found the solution. I was putting rel="text/javascript" in dataTables.min.css file